# Wrap a libpurple plugin for Adium

Tags: c, xcode, libpurple, adium

David G. F. wrote a [libpurple Plugin](https://github.com/davidgfnet/whatsapp-purple) for Whatsapp. I tested it with pidgin and it works for me. Now I try to wrap it for [Adium](https://adium.im/) ([Issue on github](https://github.com/davidgfnet/whatsapp-purple/issues/67)).

I tried to wrap a [libpurple](https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/WhatIsLibpurple) plugin for [Adium](https://adium.im/) with [this post](http://rampion.blogspot.ch/2008/09/howto-wrap-libpurple-plugin-for-adium.html). I can build the plugin and then add it to adium but nothing happens. So the **call in my wrapper** might be **wrong**. Can anyone check that? It's on github:

```
@implementation WhatsAppPlugin
- (void) installLibpurplePlugin
{
    purple_init_whatsapp_plugin();  
}
```

https://github.com/avarx/Adium-Whatsapp/blob/master/WhatsAppPlugin/WhatsAppPlugin.m

Comment: Seems like something for code review.

Comment: I didn't know about codereview.stackexchange.com. I'll post it there.

Comment: @SebastianDressler this is not for Code Review, CR is for reviewing working code posted in a question. Not for fixing not-working code provided through a link.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not Adium specialist, but when I faced with simular problem: wrap libpurple plugin for Adium, [source code of microblog-purple](http://code.google.com/p/microblog-purple/source/browse/branches/adium-merge/adium/) was very helpful. I just write same functions with little changes and everything works.

As you can see it is not enough write only installLibpurplePlugin. You should init account and service classes.